# How to duplicate SVGSurface in Cairo (Python)

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo

Say I have a surface and draw something on it.

```py
surface = cairo.SVGSurface("foo.svg", 360, 240)

ctx = cairo.Context(surface)
ctx.move_to(0, 0)
ctx.line_to(0, 80)
ctx.line_to(80, 80)
ctx.fill()
```

How do I duplicate this surface so I can draw different shapes from where I left off?

```py
surface_1 = [copy surface]
surface_2 = [copy surface]

# Draw something on surface_1
# Draw something different on surface_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: Create a new surface and draw your existing one to it.

```py
surface2 = cairo.SVGSurface("foo2.svg", 360, 240)
ctx2 = cairo.Context(surface2)
ctx2.save()
ctx2.set_source_surface(surface)
ctx2.set_operator("SOURCE")
ctx2.paint()
ctx2.restore()
```

(Note that I have no idea how PyCairo maps the C API to Python, so the above is a guess that might not work)